# Apache configure ServerPath for CodeIgniter

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I'm very new to Apache and CodeIgniter. Trying to route `/var/www/html` to `http://localhost/` and `/var/www/CodeIgniter` to `http://localhost/codeigniter`

Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerPath /codeigniter
    DocumentRoot /var/www/CodeIgniter
    <Directory /var/www/CodeIgniter>
          Allowoverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

CodeIgniter:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter';
```

`http://localhost/codeigniter` gives me codeigniter, but `http://localhost/` also gives it to me when I expect `/var/www/html`

What should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere do you configure your DocumentRoot in the snippet you give - thus we have no clue that you might be serving anything from `/var/www/html`.

I'd expect a directive `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` somewhere within your VirtualHost (I prefer such a directive in the VirtualHost, not in the global server configuration). From there on, let's look at the [Apache httpd documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#outside):

> There are frequently circumstances where it is necessary to allow web
>   access to parts of the filesystem that are not strictly underneath the
>   `DocumentRoot`. httpd offers several different ways to accomplish this.
>   On Unix systems, symbolic links can bring other parts of the
>   filesystem under the `DocumentRoot`. For security reasons, httpd will
>   follow symbolic links only if the `Options` setting for the relevant
>   directory includes `FollowSymLinks` or `SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`.
>
> Alternatively, the `Alias` directive will map any part of the filesystem
>   into the web space. For example, with
>
> `Alias "/docs" "/var/web"`
>
> the URL `http://www.example.com/docs/dir/file.html` will be served from
>   `/var/web/dir/file.html`.

i.e. I'd expect an Alias, to do the job.

```
Alias "/codeigniter" "/var/www/CodeIgniter"
```

All in all, closer to (this is not complete/tested):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html
  Alias "/codeigniter" "/var/www/CodeIgniter"
</VirtualHost>
```

(add `Options`, `Directory`, other directives and permissions etc. to taste)